# Auto resize iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've finally worked out the cross domain function for iframe. The problem I now have is the first page is quite long. When you click on a link within the iframe to a smaller page the iframe does not auto resize and you get a big gap at the bottom where the previous page height went too.

The code i'm using is the following:

Code which goes on the external domain:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, 'http://target.domain.com');">
 <h3>Got post?</h3>
 <p>Lots of stuff here which will be inside the iframe.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Code which goes on the main domain where the iframe is to be displayed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeCrossDomainIframe(id, other_domain) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      if (event.origin !== other_domain) return; // only accept messages from the specified domain
      if (isNaN(event.data)) return; // only accept something which can be parsed as a number
      var height = parseInt(event.data) + 32; // add some extra height to avoid scrollbar
      iframe.height = height + "px";
    }, false);
  }
</script>

<iframe src='http://example.com/page_containing_iframe.html' id="my_iframe"  onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('my_iframe', 'http://example.com');">
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to modify this, and if they can show what I would have to modify?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you have to ask yourself why you're using iframes. If you can accomplish this in another way (AJAX!), it's probably best. But, the only way I've seen this successful:

```
__________________
|A                |
|  ____________   |
|  |B          |  |
|  |           |  |
|  |  |C|      |  |
|  |___________|  |
|_________________|
```

Let's say A has a url of `http://foo.com` and B has a url of `http://bar.com`. No script in B can affect A. No script in A can affect the page in B. This is browser security protocol.

The only thing that A can do to B is affect the src to effectively change the page in the iframe. We can use this to our advantage.

Create a new iframe (C) inside B. C needs to come from the same server as A, so let's give it a url of `http://foo.com/iframeheight.html`. Put this at the bottom of iframe B (before the `</body>` on the iframe page):

```
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://foo.com/iframeheight.html#" + document.documentElement.scrollHeight); 
ifrm.style.width = 0+"px"; 
ifrm.style.height = 0+"px"; 
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

Because A and C have the same URL, the browser will allow them to affect each other. `http://foo.com/iframeheight.html` should contain a function to tell A to resize B:

```
window.top.getElementById('my_iframe').height = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

Comment: yeah... basically, create an iframe (C) inside your iframe (B), with the same url as the main page (A), with some sort of hash/parameter that contains the size of B, and have a script in C to tell A what size B needs to be.

Comment: yeah, sorry, forget the code you originally had. The external page gets my first piece of code to create an iframe inside of it (giving you an iframe inside an iframe). The iframe that's created loads the iframeheight.html, which needs to be a page on the server that has the main page.

Comment: Your script works? And the iframe is on a different domain than the main page? That shouldn't be...

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading into the iframe from a subdomain then this does the trick to avoid the 'Permission denied':

http://madskristensen.net/post/Iframe-cross-domain-JavaScript-calls.aspx